# Why were students seen using Levicorpus in Dumbledore's Army?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, spells

In the film of *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* we see Harry teaching the other students the spell Levicorpus in the DA meetings.

Yet Levicorpus wasn't introduced until Harry found the spell in the *Advanced Potions Making* book in *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*.

Is this a continuity error or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're confusing Levicorpus with Sectumsempra.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, your assumption is wrong.

Harry **never** taught DA the "Levicororpus" spell in OoTP **book** (confirmed by searching ebook text) - that event only happened in the movie/game based on the book, which are not canon.

---

Second, the spell was actually introduced much earlier than HBP, although not named:

- in OoTP when Harry saw Snape's memory in the Pensieve of James Potter using the spell on Snape during their time in Hogwarts.

  > ... James whirled about: a second flash of light later, Snape was hanging upside-down in the air, his robes falling over his
  >   head to reveal skinny, pallid legs and a pair of graying underpants.
- As a matter of fact, the spell was first introduced (but not named) in HP4, GoF; as we see in HBP recollection:

  > *Hermione*: "We've seen a whole bunch of people use it, in case you've forgotten. Dangling people in the air. Making them float along, asleep, helpless." Harry stared at her. With a sinking feeling, he too remembered the behaviour of the Death Eaters at the Quidditch World Cup.

So yes, apparently "they" "did think this through", as you put it.

Comment: but he shouted impedimenta instead of levicorpus

Comment: But the spell was only able to be cast when commanded non verbally,yet the caster in OoTP said it outloud

Comment: @chigri - he did BOTH spells. For different reasons. `“Impedimenta!” he said, pointing his wand at Snape, who was knocked off his feet halfway
through a dive towards his own fallen wand.`

Comment: @chigri - So did Hermione in DH (outloud).

Comment: @chigri - As far as I know, there is no spell in HP that *must* be cast non-verbally. When Snape wrote non-verbal by Levicorpus, I suspect that he thought it was just a way to gain an edge over his opponent in a duel. *‘Yes, those
who progress to using magic without shouting incantations
gain an element of surprise in their spell-casting. Not all
wizards can do this, of course.'* As not all wizards can do non-verbal spells, I wouldn't think there's a spell that requires it to be done non-verbally. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Half-Blood Prince, Snape's potion book has the incantation, and next to it N-vbl (non-verbal). James does not say the incantation in the memory, so there is no way Harry could teach the spell in the DA meetings. It seems to be a continuity error (one of many, there are very long lists online)

Answer (score 0):

No “they” didn’t think it through actually. Harry never knew the spell because when he finds it in the potions book, he doesn’t know what it does. He tests it o Ron and is surprised. He can’t have taught it if he didn’t know what it meant.

Comment: Could you [edit] in some evidence to back this up?

Comment: Harry in fact never taught Levicorpus in the DA meetings anyway, so...